# How to find the integer solution number of a linear system with inequalities?

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

I have the following system with mixed equality and inequalities defined as:

```
n = 100;
eqn = (n1 + n3 + n5 == n2 + n4 + n6) && (n1 >= 
    n2) && (n1 - n2 + n3 - n4 >= 0) && (n1 <= n) && (n1 - n2 + n3 <= 
    n) && (n1 - n2 + n3 - n4 + n5 <= n) && (2 n <= 
    n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5 + n6 <= 6 n) && (n1 > 0) && (n2 > 0) && (n3 > 0) && (n4 > 0) && (n5 > 0) && (n6 > 0);
```

How can I find all the integer solutions and especially the number of all integer solutions?

It seems `Reduce` or `Solve` does not work:

```
sol = Reduce[eqn, {n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6}, Integers]
```

produces:

```
  (n1 | n2 | n3 | n4 | n5 | n6) \[Element] 
  Integers && ((1 <= n1 <= 99 && 
     0 < n2 <= 
      n1 && ((0 < n3 < 100 - n1 && 0 < n4 <= n1 - n2 + n3 && 
         100 - n1 - n3 <= n5 <= 100 - n1 + n2 - n3 + n4 && 
         n6 == n1 - n2 + n3 - n4 + n5) || (100 - n1 <= n3 <= 
          100 - n1 + n2 && 0 < n4 <= n1 - n2 + n3 && 
         0 < n5 <= 100 - n1 + n2 - n3 + n4 && 
         n6 == n1 - n2 + n3 - n4 + n5))) || (n1 == 100 && 
     1 <= n2 <= 100 && 0 < n3 <= n2 && 0 < n4 <= 100 - n2 + n3 && 
     0 < n5 <= n2 - n3 + n4 && n6 == 100 - n2 + n3 - n4 + n5))
```

Comment: `FindInstance[eqn, {n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6}, Integers, 10]` will give you the first ten sols, but there are more ...

Comment: I tried `FIndInstance` by setting the number `10` as `10,000` instead; it has more than `10,000` solutions! The computation is very slow and has a very high demand on memory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SetSystemOptions[
  "ReduceOptions" -> {"DiscreteSolutionBound" -> 10000000}];
f[n_] := Module[{eqn},
  eqn = (n1 + n3 + n5 == n2 + n4 + n6) && (n1 >= 
      n2) && (n1 - n2 + n3 - n4 >= 0) && (n1 <= n) && (n1 - n2 + n3 <=
       n) && (n1 - n2 + n3 - n4 + n5 <= n) && (2 n <= 
      n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5 + n6 <= 6 n) && (n1 > 0) && (n2 > 
      0) && (n3 > 0) && (n4 > 0) && (n5 > 0) && (n6 > 0);
  Length@Reduce[eqn, {n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6}, Integers]]
Flatten[{#, Timing[f@#]}] & /@ Range[5, 15] // 
    TableForm[#, TableHeadings -> {None, {"n", "timing", "numbers"}}] &
```

[image]

**Edit:**
First

```
Reduce[n1 <= n, n1, Reals]
```

> n1 <= n

```
Reduce[n1 >= n2, n2, Reals]
```

> n2 <= n1

```
Reduce[n1 - n2 + n3 <= n, n3, Reals]
```

> n3 <= n - n1 + n2

```
Reduce[n1 - n2 + n3 - n4 >= 0, n4, Reals]
```

> n4 <= n1 - n2 + n3

```
Reduce[n1 - n2 + n3 - n4 + n5 <= n, n5, Reals]
```

> n5 <= n - n1 + n2 - n3 + n4

```
sol = Solve[n1 + n3 + n5 == n2 + n4 + n6, n6]
(2 n <= n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5 + n6 <= 6 n) /. sol
```

> {{n6 -> n1 - n2 + n3 - n4 + n5}}
>
> {2 n <= 2 n1 + 2 n3 + 2 n5 <= 6 n}

```
Reduce[2 n <= 2 n1 + 2 n3 + 2 n5 <= 6 n && n > 0, n5, Reals]
```

> n > 0 && n - n1 - n3 <= n5 <= 3 n - n1 - n3

```
Reduce[(n6 /. sol) > 0, n5, Reals]
```

> n5 > -n1 + n2 - n3 + n4

So the range of n5 is:

Max[-n1 + n2 - n3 + n4 + 1, n - n1 - n3, 1]< n5 < Min[3 n - n1 - n3, 
 n - n1 + n2 - n3 + n4]

```
g1 = Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
   Sum[1, {n1, n}, {n2, n1}, {n3, n - n1 + n2}, {n4, 
     n1 - n2 + n3}, {n5, Max[-n1 + n2 - n3 + n4 + 1, n - n1 - n3, 1], 
     Min[3 n - n1 - n3, n - n1 + n2 - n3 + n4]}], CompilationTarget -> "C"];
Flatten[{#, Timing[g1@#]}] & /@ Range[5, 15] // 
  TableForm[#, TableHeadings -> {None, {"n", "timing", "numbers"}}] &
```

[image]

```
g1[50] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.999057, 39324265}

```
g2 = Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
   Sum[Max[0, Min[3 n - n1 - n3, n - n1 + n2 - n3 + n4] - 
      Max[-n1 + n2 - n3 + n4 + 1, n - n1 - n3, 1] + 1], {n1, n}, {n2, 
     n1}, {n3, n - n1 + n2}, {n4, n1 - n2 + n3}], CompilationTarget -> "C"];
g2[50] // AbsoluteTiming
g2[100] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.248014, 39324265}
>
> {3.890223, 1212505405}

Comment: Thank you! Where can I 学到 learn such insights in using Mathematica this way? It seems the online documents of Wolfram have no such contents.

Comment: One possible issue is when $n$ increases, the memory demand becomes high quickly. If only solution number is required, can it be improved to be more efficient and less memory demanding?

Comment: +1 for a great answer and your first Enlightened badge. :-)